# iPhone Go Button does not hide keyboard for JQuery Mobile 1.4.3 Remote Autocomplete

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I am using the code from the JQuery Mobile 1.4.3 Remote Autocomplete and would like the Go button to hide the keyboard as it did for 1.3.2. It does not hide the keyboard for 1.4.3 but does for 1.3.2

Here's the link from 1.4.3 http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview-autocomplete-remote/ Here's the link for 1.3.2 http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html